# Uso de "estar" en un contexto donde normalmente se usaria "ser"

Tags: argentina, cópulas

Yo soy brasileño y desde Febrero estoy viviendo en Argentina.

No sé si esta cuestión tiene que ver solamente con el español argentino/rioplatense o es una cuestión general.

El tema es lo siguiente:

La diferencia entre **ser** y **estar** es que, mientras el primero significa un estado permanente o prolongado ( esencia ), el segundo significa un estado **actual**.

Estos verbos también existen y son usados de esta misma forma en portugués.

No en tanto percibí que **estar** en algunos casos es usado de una forma que se debería usar el verbo **ser**.

Por ejemplo, cuando estábamos hablando acerca de un juego que nos gustaba con un de mis amigos, yo le dije:

> Este juego ¡**es** muy bueno!

Al que él contestó:

> Sí, ¡**está** rebueno!

Yo construí mi expresión de la misma forma que hablaría en portugués:

> Este jogo **é** muito bom!

Pero me parece que en algunos casos se usa el verbo **estar** con este sentido, como lo hizo mí amigo, y ya vi también otros usarlo de esta forma.

Mi duda es:

- ¿Es este fenómeno exclusivo o predominante en el español argentino/rioplatense?
- ¿Es este fenómeno exclusivo de la lengua hablada?
- ¿Cuáles son los casos en que se manifiesta este fenómeno y en que casos no se debe usar **estar** con este sentido de **ser**?

Comment: La misma cosa pasa en portugués. O jogo é bom. O jogo está bom.

Comment: En portugués se usaria "o jogo está bom", por ejemplo, en una partida de futbol, que está pasando en este instante. Pero quando hablamos, como en ele ejemplo citado, de un juego de computadora que nos gustava, usaríamos em portugués: "o jogo é bom".

Comment: Estou dizendo que em português e em espanhol é exatamente a mesma coisa. "O jogo é bom, e, hoje está ainda melhor".  El juego es bueno e  hoy está aun mejor.

Comment: E eu, estou dizendo que a expressão "este juego está bueno" é completamente estranha para um falante nativo de português (brasileiro), já que, no contexto supracitado, NUNCA usaríamos o verbo estar, e sim o verbo ser. Minha pergunta deriva desse estranhamento.

Comment: A diferença entre (jogo de video ou até futebol) entre estar e ser é igualzinho em português. "Cara, esse jogo tá bom, né?" Ou seja, o fato de assistir ao  jogo em um momento dado. Comparado a: "O jogo é bom mesmo" (em termos absolutos). Ë a mesma coisa em espanhol. E foi isso que o cara estava dizendo. O momento estava bom. Qualquer coisa pode estar bom ou ser bom. Um é no momento, o outro descreve o estado normal da coisa.

Comment: Não estávamos assistindo nem jogando nenhum jogo, portanto não havia um contexto de "momento". O seguinte diálogo não faz nenhum sentido em português: "Você já jogou Age of Empires? Está muito bom!" "Sim, já joguei, está muito bom!" O uso do "estar", nesse caso, é completamente inadequado e estranho, mas é utilizado dessa forma em espanhol.

Comment: Por definição quando o seu amigo falou: está rebueno, ele está se referindo à coisa como se fosse algo comestível o que se consome. Do estilo: Esse filme é muito bom. Resposta: Sim, está muito bom. Acho que nesse sentido seria igual em português. Essa menina é linda. Resposta: Sim, está boa. :)

Comment: Não sei se você é falante nativo de português, mas o exemplo que você deu definitiamente não faz sentido. O exemplo do filme pode fazer sentido se estivermos assitindo ao filme naquele momento, o que não é o caso que eu citei, onde falávamos de jogos sem estar jogando jogos. O exemplo do filme, no entanto, não faz sentido se não estivermos assistindo ao filme. Já o caso da menina, não faz sentido em um contexto em que estamos comentando de uma menina que está passando ou algo do tipo. Talvez fizesse sentido se os dois amigos estivessem, por exemplo, juntos, em um ato sexual com a menina

Comment: De qualquer forma, em todos os casos, o sentido só existe quando o ato (jogar, assistir a um filme, "experimentar" uma menina) está acontecendo. Quando não, usaríamos, indubitavelmente, o verbo ser.

Comment: Mateus, tudo bem. Deixemos o assunto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- *¿Es este fenómeno exclusivo o predominante en el español argentino/rioplatense?*

No, no es un fenómeno exclusivo del español argentino/rioplatense.

- *¿Es este fenómeno exclusivo de la lengua hablada?*

No, no es un fenómeno exclusivo de la lengua hablada, también aparece en forma literaria.

- *¿Cuáles son los casos en que se manifiesta este fenómeno y en que casos no se debe usar estar con este sentido de ser ?*

Abajo se indican.

---

---

---

Aquí te dejo transcrito los usos de Ser y Estar de una página dedicada a la enseñanza del español que lo aclara bastante bien.

---

**Usos de Ser y Estar**

"*Muchos estudiantes de español tienen problemas con el uso de ser y estar. **Los dos verbos tienen algunos casos en que su uso es exclusivo, pero el problema llega cuando hay adjetivos que admiten los dos usos**. Aquí podéis encontrar un resumen de sus principales usos:*"

**SER**

- Identificar: Soy Nuria.
- Nacionalidad: Es danés.
- Descripciones y características inherentes a una persona: -- El cielo es azul.
- Profesión: Somos médicos.
- Valorar un hecho, cosa o persona: Trabajar en casa es más relajado.
- Hora: Son las diez de la mañana.
- Marcar una fracción o periodo de tiempo: Es de día, es lunes.
- Referirse a la celebración de un acontecimiento o suceso: - - La fiesta es en mi casa.

**ESTAR**

- Ubicar o localizar cosas, lugares y personas: El museo está en el centro de la ciudad.
- Hablar del estado físico o de ánimo: Está deprimido.
- Marcar el resultado de una acción o el final de un proceso: - La puerta está abierta, está muerto.
- Con gerundio, marca una acción en desarrollo: Marta está durmiendo.
- Procede a bien/mal: El ejercicio está bien.
- Con la preposición “de” indica un trabajo temporal: Está de camarero.
- En la primera persona del plural se usa para situarnos en el tiempo: Estamos a 3 de mayo.

---

**SER y ESTAR**

**Algunos adjetivos tienen un significado completamente diferente dependiendo de si van con ser/estar.**

Aquí tienes algunos ejemplos:

- **Ser rico**: tener mucho dinero. Juan es muy rico, el año pasado ganó la lotería.
- **Estar rico**: sabroso, de buen sabor. Esta paella está muy rica, ¿quieres un poco?
- **Ser bueno**: ser honesto, de buen corazón. Mis padres son muy buenos conmigo, siempre que necesito algo me ayudan.
- **Estar bueno**: ser sexy, atractivo: Brad Pitt está muy bueno.
- **Ser negro**: de color negro: Este abrigo es de color negro.
- **Estar negro**: estar muy moreno después de tomar el sol, estar sucio, estar enfadado: Jaime está negro, lleva esperando el autobús más de una hora. La casa está negra, hace más de una semana que nadie limpia. Marisa ha vuelto de vacaciones y está negra, ha tomado el sol cada día.
- **Ser cerrado**: persona introvertida. Mi compañero de trabajo es muy cerrado, nunca habla con nadie.
- **Estar cerrado**: lugar que no está abierto: Es muy tarde, el supermercado ya está cerrado.
- **Ser listo**: persona inteligente. Pedro habla siete idiomas, es un chico muy listo.
- **Estar listo**: Estar preparado para algo: ¿Estáis listos? Vamos a llegar tarde!
- **Ser verde**: color de las plantas y otras cosas: Pintaremos la casa de verde.
- **Estar verde**: algo inmaduro o alguien inexperto: Estoy muy verde todavía, no puedo hablar español muy bien.
- **Ser claro**: algo que tiene luz, transparente: Esta casa tiene muchas ventanas, es muy clara.
- **Estar claro**: explicación o concepto sencillo: ¿Está claro o lo vuelvo a explicar?

---

**Usos de Ser y Estar**

https://laemadrid.com/es/usos-de-ser-y-estar/

---

P.D. Existe un libro, ya antiguo pero entretenido, sobre los supuestos mal entendidos del lenguaje y muy aconsejable para aquellos que deseen estudiar español. El libro se llama, "La Tesis de Nancy Ramón J. Sender".

La tesis de Nancy refleja la España de su tiempo que a través de los ojos de una sorprendida estudiante norteamericana. Escrita en genero epistolar, es decir, compuestas de cartas.
Más abajo te dejo un enlace a la carta nº1 de las diez que se compone la novela.

- Carta 1ª− Nancy descubre Sevilla

> Me suceden cosas raras con demasiada frecuencia. Y no se puede decir
> que los hombres sean descorteses, no. Al contrario, se preocupan del
> color de mi pelo y hasta de mi salud. En la puerta del café hay
> siempre gente joven, y cuando vuelvo a casa veo que alguno me mira y
> dice: **«Está buena»**. Yo no puedo menos de agradecerles con una sonrisa
> **su preocupación por mi salud.**

En este apartado, en uno de esos mal entendidos, los jóvenes le dicen que "**Está buena**", es decir **atractiva**, mientras ella interpreta que ellos se preocupan por su **salud**. (pag. 12, nº 4 del pdf)

http://data.ecasals.net/pdf/24/9788483431788_L33_24.pdf

[image]

Comment: ¡Hola, @Diego! La primera sección de su respuesta, "usos de ser y estar", estes usos son practicamente los mismos que en portugués. Creo que la llave para esta cuestión está en el uso idiosincrático de los verbos con adjetivos específicos, como citado en la segunda sección. Si entendi bien, me parece que decir "este juego es muy bueno" significaria que el juego es un juego "honesto, de buen corazón", o que no tiene sentido, mientras decir "este juego está muy bueno" significaria que el juego és bien hecho, divertido. Me entendi bien?

Comment: "Este juego es muy bueno", "esta chica esta muy buena", "este chico esta muy bueno"."Bueno" puede tener otros significados. En "este juego es muy bueno" o "este juego está bueno" coinciden los significado. "Que es divertido y entretenido para la persona". Por otro lado es distinto la utilización del verbo ser o estar en las expresiones, mientras que en Europa normalmente decimos ¡ este juego es muy entretenido! o ¡ este juego esta muy bien!, para expresar que es grato o atractivo, en países de ibero-américa la expresión utilizada es, ¡este juego está muy bueno!. "Atractivo o interesante".

Comment: No te preocupes ya iras poco a poco diferenciando este tipo de términos y las situaciones nuevas que cada idioma crea con el lenguaje.